# ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception while using for loop

Tags: javascript

THIS CODE IS NOT WORKING, PLEASE HELP !!!

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException is thrown by compiler, Please HELP !!!

```
for(var i=1;i<='<%=count%>';+++)
{
var x = document.getElementById("person");
var opt =  document.createElement("option");
opt.text = '<%=list[i]%>';          <------------------ ERROR IS AT THIS LINE
opt.value = '<%=list[i]%>'; 
x.add(opt);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it should be `I <= '<%=count%>'` instead of `I < '<%=count%>'`?

Comment: This is a **Java** question hiding behind a `javascript` tag. JavaScript doesn't **have** `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`. **Java** does. They're different languages, with different (though similar) syntax, and different (not very similar) models of operation. If we assume that your Java code has `list` and it's an **array** (not a list) and that `count` comes from `list.length`, then this is [a duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it).

Comment: Well, mostly. You're also assuming `i` in your JSP code (on the server, as the page is getting ready to be sent to the client) will magically be `i` in your JavaScript code (on the client, later, when the page is loaded and the client-side code is run).

Comment: please, please, please visit this page - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553705/local-variable-cannot-be-resolved. It is having the full code, and my refined question... PLEASE HELP ME SIR !!! I HAVE TO SUBMIT THIS PROJECT !!

Comment: Local VARIABLE CANNOT BE RESOLVED?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/34553705/5734115?sem=2


PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE HELP ME...

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what u mean. What is count?

```
var x = document.getElementById("person");
for(var i = 0; i < '<%=count%>';i++) {
   var opt =  document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = '<%=list[i]%>';
   opt.value = '<%=list[i]%>'; 
   x.add(opt);
}
```

Comment: here, count is a variable used in the same jsp page, and its value is equal to the number of rows in the database, and the list is a String array variable which is holding the items or the value of a particular column of a database, through getString() method. Please help me !!

Comment: this is a common error(catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) which comes whenever m trying to iterate using for loop, and assigning the values of a column from a table of a database, and setting the limit for - for loop as the number of rows... please help me !!!

Comment: I cannot help you more than this. You have to show what list and count are generated. Did you try the solution which I posted?

Comment: please, please, please visit this page - stackoverflow.com/questions/34553705/…. It is having the full code, and my refined question... PLEASE HELP ME SIR !!!