# Local variable cannot be resolved?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, for-loop

In this code, I am putting the values of MySQL database into `String array(list[count])` and `count=number` of rows in table in database. And while I am applying `for-loop` to print these values in the drop-down list in javascript, using `j` variable, compiler is not able to recognize the `j`. I am not able to understand why. Please help me.

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<html>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<div align="center"><h1>Task Assignment</h1></div>
<form name="taskassignment"><div align="center"><table>
<tr><td><font size="5">Person(s)</font></td><td><select id="person"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td><font size="5">Task(s)</font></td><td><select name="task"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Assign" name="assigntask"/></td></tr></div></table></form>
<%
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BI","root","mayur");
String query = "select name from records";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
int count =0;
while(rs.next())
{
count++;    
}

String[] list = new String[count];
int i=0;
rs.beforeFirst();
while(rs.next())
{

list[i] = rs.getString(1);
out.println(list[i]);
i++;

}

%>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
for(var j=1;j<=<%=list.length%>;j++)
{
    var x = document.getElementById("person");
    var opt =  document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = '<%=list[j]%>';
    opt.value = '<%=list[j]%>'; 
    x.add(opt);

}
}
window.onload = myFunction;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are mixing client side with server side code.

Comment: you're confused between server side code and client side code ... j is defined in javascript, but the page has already failed to load because server side has no idea what j is

Comment: Sir, please suggest me how to retrieve values from database and put them in drop down list of script ???

Answer (score 0):

Consider this jsp scriplet to fill your select. I used comment to highlight things of notice. Once you have this working make sure to read on JSTL - Scriplets are very oldschool.

```
<select id="person">
<%
//no longer needed for 99% of jdbc drivers
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());

//Dont EVER post realusernames/passwords!
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BI","root","mayur");
String query = "select name from records";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()) {
   String item = rs.getString(1);
   //now produce html select
%><option value='<%= item %>'><%= item %></option><%
}
rs.close ();
stmt.close ();
conn.close ();
%>
</select>
```

More notes:

- think of using a connection pool. Establishing connections is expensive
- try-with-resource can help minimize catching/closing code overhead
- check jstl

Answer (score 0):

Hi Mayur i changed the query as per my table and also little bit code. Please modify it as per requirement. I tested in my local & it is adding all the fields.It will work but as Jan suggested refer JSTL also , as scriptlets are hard to maintain

```
    <%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
    <%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<html>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<div align="center"><h1>Task Assignment</h1></div>
<%

String hiddenResult = "";
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wiprodb","root","1234");
String query = "select state from state_tb";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
int count =0;
while(rs.next())
{

    hiddenResult = hiddenResult+ (rs.getString(1))+",";   
}

hiddenResult = hiddenResult.substring(0, hiddenResult.length()-1);

%>

<form name="taskassignment">

<input type="hidden" id="hiddenDDResult" name="hiddenDDResult" value="<%=hiddenResult%>" />
<div align="center">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><font size="5">Person(s)</font></td>
    <td><select id="person"></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><font size="5">Task(s)</font></td>
    <td><select name="task"></select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Assign" name="assigntask"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
</form>

<script>
function myFunction()
{

    var ddResult = document.getElementById("hiddenDDResult").value;
    var ddElement = document.getElementById("person");

    var tempValue = ddResult.split(",");
    //alert('ddResult'+ddResult);
for(var i=0;i<tempValue.length;i++)
{
    var opt =  document.createElement("option");
    opt.text = tempValue[i];
    opt.value = tempValue[i];  
    ddElement.add(opt);

}
}
myFunction();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not tested, but something like below should work

```
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<html>
<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<div align="center"><h1>Task Assignment</h1></div>
<form name="taskassignment"><div align="center"><table>
<tr><td><font size="5">Person(s)</font></td><td>

<select id="person">


<%
DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BI","root","mayur");
String query = "select name from records";
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
int count =0;
while(rs.next())
{
count++;    
}

String[] list = new String[count];
int i=0;
rs.beforeFirst();
while(rs.next())
{

list[i] = rs.getString(1);
out.println(list[i]);
%>
<option value='<%=list[i]%>'><%=list[i]%></option>
<% 
i++;
}
%>

</select>

</td></tr>
<tr><td><font size="5">Task(s)</font></td><td><select name="task"></select></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Assign" name="assigntask"/></td></tr></div></table></form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankyou sir, but i have to put multiple values, this code will print only one value of array?

Comment: It should print multiple values, as `<option value='<%=list[i]%>'><%=list[i]%></option>` in while loop